# Super complex Schema will not migrate to PaaS

Tags: sql-server-2016, schema, migration, azure

Using a Dedicated 2016 datacentre SQL Server 2 vcpus, 14 GiB memory for testing.

We have currently found a migration issue with the database Migration SQL 2016 to Azure PaaS.
The transfer of schema and data of the database is too complex for any migration process attempted. So far tested using only using a database with 65 schemas (712 tables per schema) plus 20000 base tables using a dev database. In live we have some 3000 schemas split into 10 clusters, so the issue is going to be exacerbated. "Database works, with 2 customers and run through DMA all good"

•   Database migration service – This requires schemas to be deployed first, No schema exists in Source control of the schools exist in the data only baseline schema

•   Redgate – SQL compare this Identified 62000 tables and crashed on deployment script creation

•   Export Data-Tier Application and Deploy database to Azure, first failed with “The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.” the reason was related to a complex database schema, which took longer to evaluate than the 60 seconds this was overcome with changing the following registry key to set the query timeout for the BACPAC export:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SQLDB\Database\QueryTimeoutSeconds (REG_DWORD) set 6000 The tool failed with an insufficient memory problem

•   Generate Database script within SSMS in attempt to use import data via DMS failed SSMS crashed after 6 hours

•   Export Data tool identified tables and only went 27% through before crashing.

We have a backup .bak but as schemas are created per customer there is no scripted source control of the whole database, as updates are looped through each schema.

**Open to suggestions where you have come across a similar scenario and have a solution.**

Clarification
I would like both database structure and data .

But one step at a time . I could use ADMS to move data post schema or export data.

We do not have the entire database under source control because when we onboard a new customer a replicated set of tables with a new schema is added to the database.

23/06/2021 Just attempted with SQL 2019 Dev 4 core 32GB and still an issue.

Comment: Hiya. I am a Redgate employee. If you are willing and able to open a support ticket, then we would love to help you out with the issue you had on SQL Compare. You can start a ticket here: https://productsupport.red-gate.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Hi Kendra I can raise a ticket but this looks a step too far for the tool. I did request assistance with the deployment for the database through SCA, but was infrom that it is not designed to iterate through schemas.

Comment: Kendra raised  253178

Comment: If you could clarify some of the points you made, you may be able to gather more attention and help to the question. I see you've attempted to use a few migration services and features of SQL Server, but it's unclear if you're having issues trying to migrate the structure, the data, or both at the same time. Additionally, I was specifically confused when you said "*We have a backup .bak but as schemas are created per customer the is no scripted source control of the whole database*"...are you trying to migrate a single database?...if so, all schemas of that database should be in its backup.